# If Exists statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am executing below statement on Sql server 2012. But it always execute even though column doesnt exist

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Age')
begin
  Print 'in'
  Update Table1 set Age = Null

End
```

I also tried below

```
if exists(select * from sys.columns 
      where Name = 'Age' and Object_ID = Object_ID('Table1'))
```

Executing both statement gives error `Invalid column name Age`

Dont understand why it goes inside `Begin` block.

Comment: Correct schema? (Someone else may have another Table1...)

Comment: No thats not the case

Comment: Your age column exists ?

Comment: No it doesnt exist anymore in that table

Comment: its works fine for me did you found Age as column name  in `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' `??

Comment: how can you update your column if does not exists in the table? Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS it is working in my case

Comment: @KhurramAli i first check if column exist. If exist then set to Null and then next i rename that column and change data type to int. I checked in Information_schema_columns and column Age dont exist

Comment: what is your data type of age column ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exists` statement is working.  The problem is the `update`.  Your code is being compiled *before* the `if` is being run.  So, the error occurs during the compile stage.

You can fix this by using dynamic SQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Age')
begin
  Print 'in'
  exec sp_executesql N'Update Table1 set Age = Null';
End;
```

Comment: Thank you its working. May i know what is use of sp_execute_sql ?

Comment: @Happy . . . It is an improved version of the `exec` command.

Comment: Please replace sp_execute_sql  by  sp_executesql

Answer (score 0):

Upon execution SQL server tries to compile the stored procedure and fails to do so. Applying a bit of dynamic sql will solve your problem:

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Age')
begin
  Print 'in'
  EXEC sp_executesql 'Update Table1 set Age = Null'
End
```