# Injecting variable in nested EXEC in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, exists

New to SQL and i'm working on a separate network so i can't share snippets (sorry) so bare with me please.

I have a stored procedure that has a table injected, based on this table i want it to run a specific part of the script (if else else if...)

Before I start adding the ELSEs i want to ensure the IF first works.
It goes something like this within my alter procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TestProc (@table VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 
   N'IF EXISTS (SELECT PersonID FROM ' + @table + ')
      BEGIN 
      EXEC SP_EXECUTIONSQL N''''
         INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(PerID, Name, Age) SELECT T.PerID, T.Name, T.Age 
         FROM ''' + @table + ''' T  
         END' 
-- Before the apostrophe on the END i'd add the else, but again, i want to test this first.   
EXEC (SQL); 
END
```

The issue i'm having when i run  `EXEC TestProc 'Employees'` is **Incorrect syntax near 'Employees' -** the nested injected @table in the second FROM.

For background, I am nesting the EXEC SP_EXECUTIONSQL Because i was having the same issue as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645091/if-exists-statement-not-working).
Also, i simplified my table significantly for various reasons, so alternative solutions may not be feasible.

I tried just using IF ELSE statements normally, but i discovered from a previously [posted question](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) that everything is compiled before the IF statement, and so the injected table overrides the IF statement and injects it into IF and every ELSE i throw in there.

What i was expecting was for the script to stop once the conditions of the IF ELSE were met.

Comment: Table names don't have `'` around them. Try `QUOTENAME(@table)` and SQL Server will apply the correct quoting for you. As an aside, this is a huge security flaw; if any rogue actor gets access to this, they can execute almost anything *(SQL Inject attack, but made easier)*.

Comment: Why are you using `EXEC(@SQL)` to call a statement that then uses `sys.sp_executesql` anyway? Why not just use `sys.sp_executesql`? You say you're having the "same problem" as the other person, but for the above, there's no need for "dynamic dynamic" SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes that your shouldn't and missing quotes that you need. You also have a typo `so_executionsql` should be `sp_executesql`.

I reformatted your code to make it easier.

Try this...

```
SET @sql = N'
  IF EXISTS (SELECT PersonID FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE) + ')
  BEGIN 
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N''
      INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(PerID, Name, Age)
        SELECT T.PerID, T.Name, T.Age 
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE) + ' T
    '';
  END
'
```

In fact, you don't even need the nested calls to exec...

```
SET @sql = N'
  IF EXISTS (SELECT PersonID FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE) + ')
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(PerID, Name, Age)
      SELECT T.PerID, T.Name, T.Age 
      FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE) + ' T;
  END
'
```